# How to import intl library in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, intl, flutter-intl

I am new in Flutter.  When I import the library: `import 'package:intl/intl.dart';` , it says that `the target of URI doesn't exist:package:intl/intl.dart;`
[image]

Comment: Just to double check, you did import intl: ^0.15.7 into pubspec.yaml; triple check that it has four spaces in front of it (no more and no less); and you ran packages get?

Also, put your focus on the tab for main.dart and hit the green arrow to run it. Sometimes you will then see a popup bar at the top of the screen that tells you pubspec.yaml has changed and you need to run it again from that link in order for it to take. (I've seen that in IntelliJ)

Let us know if that doesn't help.

Comment: It works now. Thanks! But it is still showing the red underlines. Is there a way to solve it ? @scottstoll2017

Comment: If it's showing red lines under publspec.yaml in the project window but everything is working, that's a bug in the analysis. Ignore it but yes, they do know about it and are working on it. It's often there because, for some reason, pubspec.yaml says your assets directory doesn't exist even though you can access the assets without any problem.

Comment: @scottstoll2017 No it is showing under main.dart (as shown in the picture in my question)

Comment: Try stopping the app, going to the terminal and running "flutter clean"

Also, there is a chance that you might have a second import that is trying to use a different class with the same name, but try the clean first.

Comment: What does Dart Analysis say when you check it?
(Bottom bar in IntelliJ)

Comment: Problem solved! I flutter clean didn't do anything. I just restarted IntelliJ and red lines are gone

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just to double check, you did import intl: ^0.15.7 into pubspec.yaml; triple check that it has four spaces in front of it (no more and no less); and you ran packages get?

Also, put your focus on the tab for main.dart and hit the green arrow to run it. Sometimes you will then see a popup bar at the top of the screen that tells you pubspec.yaml has changed and you need to run it again from that link in order for it to take. (I've seen that in IntelliJ)

Also, if it's showing red lines under publspec.yaml in the project window but everything is working, that's a bug in the analysis. Ignore it but yes, they do know about it and are working on it. It's often there because, for some reason, pubspec.yaml says your assets directory doesn't exist even though you can access the assets without any problem.

Answer (score 30):

When you import any package, example:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

You need to also add the package inside the [`pubspec.yaml`](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec) file under the `dependencies` field example:

```
dependencies:
  intl: ^0.15.7
```

Then from the terminal you can execute the following command:

```
flutter packages get
```

or

From Android Studio/IntelliJ:

Click `Packages Get` in the action ribbon at the top of `pubspec.yaml`

more info here:

https://flutter.io/using-packages/

Answer (score 4):

Let IDE do this for you :

```
flutter pub add intl
```

After running above command, It will resolve the dependency with the latest version available.

OR
**Manual Process**

**1)** Add package in `pubspec.yaml` file under dependencies field :

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  intl: ^0.17.0   // Add this line
```

**2)** Execute the following command in terminal :

```
flutter packages get
```

**3)** Import package in your dart file :

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are facing errors while installing
it coming because of your old version of SDK.

Just fall back to the intl version back by some points in your pubs
intl: ^0.17.0 ---> intl: ^0.16.1  or any other older version like intl: ^0.15.1  etc.
Sometimes its the version of packages which after update not compatible with your old sdk

Comment: I don't know why they negativate, this tip worked for me. Thanks. You basically needs to install an older version and then upgrade to a new one.